# Can`t deploy with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I can`t deploy using Jenkins Pipeline
And I checked successful process of building, pushing

How to deploy this pipeline? :(

```
> [Pipeline] kubernetesDeploy Starting Kubernetes deployment Loading
> configuration: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Hello-Kenzan
> Pipeline/applications/hello-kenzan/k8s/deployment.yaml ERROR: ERROR:
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation:
> [get]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [hello-kenzan]  in namespace:
> [default]  failed. hudson.remoting.ProxyException:
> io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation:
> [get]  for kind: [Service]  with name: [hello-kenzan]  in namespace:
> [default]  failed.
```

Comment: sounds suspiciously like an RBAC failure; can you list services using `kubectl` and the credential under which jenkins is trying to do that deployment?